# The usage to 'study' and 'revise'

Tags: meaning, british-english

I've heard many people say that

> I am going to study tonight for tomorrow's test

Is the usage of 'study' in that sentence correct? If so, why? Would the usage of *revise* be better in that sentence?

I have done a little of definition finding as came out with this:

> Study: Application of the mind to the acquisition of knowledge, as by reading, investigation, or reflection
>
> Revise: To review (previously studied materials) in preparation for an examination.

Sources:

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/study

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/revise

Comment: Well, realistically, most people doesn't start reading their notes until the night of the test, so they're actually studying instead of revising.

Comment: By your linked definitions of *revise*, your definition seems to be BrE usage. I would not use it as such in AmE, where its changing or amending something.

Comment: @user3169 what do you mean by BrE and AmE? Can you expand it if it is an abbreviation?

Comment: British English vs American English - Revise is BrE, study is AmE - hence the current confusion in this thread ;)

Comment: So, what I have summed up so far is that _revise_ is more commonly accepted in BrE whereas in AmE, study is more commonly used in the sample sentence above. Am I right?

Comment: *Review* or *go over* could be used in AmE to mean *revise* in BrE. See also: http://separatedbyacommonlanguage.blogspot.com/2006/12/revision.html.

Answer (score 1):

User3169 brings up a good point. The only meaning of revise in the US is

> to alter something already written or printed, in order to make corrections, improve, or update:

I have actually never heard the British meaning before today!

Cultural language differences aside, I don't think that you could say

> I am going to revise tonight for tomorrow's test

*Study* in the first sentence is being used as an [intransitive verb](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/intransitiveverb.htm) which means that there is no direct object. You could use it as a transitive verb, and say "I am going to study *the textbooks* tonight..."

Now, I don't speak British English, so I might be wrong, but to me *revise* sounds like it should be a transitive verb. So you should instead say

> I am going to revise the textbooks tonight for tomorrow's test.

However, if someone who does speak British English disagrees, let me know.

Comment: In the UK, you study all year - you only revise what you already studied, just before the test/exam. Your sentence "I am going to revise tonight for tomorrow's test" would be perfectly acceptable & easily understood in BrE.

Comment: In a UK school, during exam season, "What are you doing tonight?" "Revising" or "Revision." would be a very common exchange, needing no further explanation other than perhaps what [educational] subject it refers to.